# Hibernate Oracle connection error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a problem with my application
When I try to access from hibernate to my database after long time without restart of Tomcat I get this error:

```
Line 2130 : Exception in thread "OracleTimeoutPollingThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Line 2131 : at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTimeoutPollingThread.pollOnce(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:209)
Line 2132 : at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTimeoutPollingThread.run(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:166)
Line 2133 : #
Line 2134 : # An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
Line 2135 : #
Line 2136 : # EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d394aca, pid=4160, tid=5848
Line 2137 : #
Line 2138 : # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_09-b03 mixed mode)
Line 2139 : # Problematic frame:
Line 2140 : # C [tcnative-1.dll+0x4aca]
Line 2141 : #
Line 2142 : # An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid4160.log
Line 2143 : #
Line 2144 : # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
Line 2145 : # http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
Line 2146 : #
Line 2147 :
Line 2148 : 2012-08-16 13:27:52 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

Anybody know what can be a problem in my code?
Maybe firewall or something else?
Note: I use my connection in c3p0
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your "hs_err_pid4160.log" - may be something useful there

Comment: please see http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/312-exception_access_violation-0xc0000005.html. Reinstall your JVM and if possible upgrade to the latest patch on 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a jvm crash which is usually a java bug unless you are using native code through JNI.

Your java version is rather old, you should upgrade to last 1.5 version or if you can to 1.6.

Try to look at the content of hs_err_pid4160.log as suggested by konstantin to exclude some memory misconfiguration and paste its content here if you want us to help you